# what does if (!ifstream) mean in c++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I found this code and I don't know what the !ist means.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
int main()
{
    string readname;
    cin >> readname;
    ifstream ist{ readname };
    if (!ist)
    {
        //insert any text here
    }
}
```

I don't know what the (!ist) is for. I have tried to figure out what this means but i cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::basic_ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) inherits [`std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

> Checks whether the stream has no errors.
>
> Returns true if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O
>   operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

So the code is equivalent with (all of the following):

```
if (!static_cast<bool>(ist))
if (!ist.operator bool())
if (!!ist.fail())

if (ist.fail())
```

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the boolean "not" operator, so this tests `ist` to see if it is *not* valid -- if it failed to be able to open the specified file and read from it.